Use mintinline with a colored rounded box background and display a single brace?
I would like to have inline code examples with a light gray background color. I can achieve the desired result with the following:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setminted{style=trac}

\newtcbox{\mintinlinebox}{on line,
  boxsep=0pt, left=1.5pt, right=1.5pt, top=1pt, bottom=1pt,
  colframe=gray!20, colback=gray!20,
  rounded corners,
  boxrule=0pt}

\newcommand{\cde}[2]{%
  \mintinlinebox{\mintinline{#1}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\cde{python}{print("Hello, World!")}

\mintinline{python}|}| 
\cde{python}{ \} }

\end{document}

However, wrapping a tcolorbox around mintinline disable the use of | notation. Therefore, I don't know how to display a single brace. It works with \mintinline{text}|}| but not with \cde{text}{}}. Even \cde{text}{\}} doesn't work because it adds the backslash.
Is it possible to achieve the same result, but either:

Find a way to display a single brace and be agnostic of the code content
Or do some magic to use the | notation.

Note that I am auto-generating my document, I need a repeatable way to render my code. With the pipe notation it is straightforward to escape &, # and %.

Use \NewTotalTCBox with a v (verbatim) second argument. The argument can be between a pair of identical characters, line for \verb, but also braced if there aren't unbalanced braces.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setminted{style=trac}

\NewTotalTCBox{\mintinlinebox}{mv}{
  on line,
  boxsep=0pt,
  left=1.5pt,
  right=1.5pt,
  top=1pt,
  bottom=1pt,
  colframe=gray!20,
  colback=gray!20,
  rounded corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
}{\mintinline{#1}{#2}}


\begin{document}

\mintinlinebox{python}{print("Hello, Wórld!")}

\mintinlinebox{python}|}|

\end{document}



Indeed, It works much better with the diacritic on the o :)
